# Divisibility criteria for 3 in sum of power of sum of digits

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, decimal-expansion

Following things motivated by [previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4171572/647719).

Consider $a, b$ and $c$ are integer with $a\ge1$ and $b\ge 2$.

Function $D(a, b)$ define as sum of digit of $a$ in base $b$. Example $D(5,2)=2$.

Let $$f(a,b,c)=\sum_{k=1}^ac^{D(k, b)}$$

Example $f(5,2,-1)=(-1)^{D(1,2)}+(-1)^{D(2,2)}+(-1)^{D(3,2)}+(-1)^{D(4,2)}+(-1)^{D(5,2)}=(-1)+(-1)+1+(-1)+1=-1.$

Clearly  If $c\equiv 0\pmod3$ then $f(a, b, c)\equiv 0\pmod3$.

Questions; are the following claims true

1. If $c\equiv 1\pmod3$ then $f(a, b, c)\equiv a\pmod3$?
2. If $c\equiv 2\pmod3$ and $a\equiv1\pmod2$ then $f(a, b, c)\equiv2\pmod3$?
3. what is criteria for $f(a, b, c)\pmod3$ when $c\equiv2\pmod3$ and $a\equiv 0\pmod2$?

Source code PARI/GP

```
for(a=1,100,print([a, a%3,sum(k=1,a,(-2)^sumdigits(k, 2))%3]))
```

Table, note we take $c=10,-2\equiv 1\pmod3$

$$\begin{array}{|c |c |c|c|c|c|}  \hline a & a\pmod3 & f(a, 10,10) &f(a, 2,10)&f(a, 10,-2)&f\pmod3 \\ \hline
1& 1& 10&10&-2& 1 \\  \hline
2& 2& 110&20&2& 2\\  \hline
3& 0& 1110&120&-6& 0\\  \hline
4& 1& 11110&130&10& 1\\  \hline
5& 2& 111110&230&-22& 2\\  \hline
6& 0& 1111110&330&42& 0\\  \hline
13& 1& 1111122220&3640&-332& 1\\  \hline
14& 2& 1111222220&4640&-364& 2\\  \hline
15& 0& 1112222220&14640&-300& 0\\  \hline
16& 1& 1122222220&14650&-428& 1\\  \hline
17& 2& 1222222220&14750&-172& 2\\  \hline
18& 0& 2222222220&14850&-684& 0\\  \hline
19& 1& 12222222220&15850&340& 1\\  \hline
 \end{array}$$

Similarly, we can check more calculations to confirm.

---

The solution to 1st claim

Note $(3u+1)^x\equiv 1\pmod3$ thus, when $c\equiv 1\pmod3$ then $f(a, b, c)\equiv 1+1+...+1(a \text{times})\equiv a\pmod3$

Now $2^{nd}$ and $3^{rd}$ questions are left.

Comment: parsum the sum digits, and parfor a%3 ? Oh and use Fermat to mod the exponent modulo 2 to reduce computation of large exponents ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second claim is true.

First of all, let us prove the following lemma :

**Lemma** : If $b$ is odd, then for every positive integer $\ell$, $$(-1)^{D(\ell,b)}+(-1)^{D(\ell+1,b)}=0\tag1$$

*Proof* :

Let $a_i$ be the $i$-th digit (from the right) of $\ell$ in base $b$. Let $n$ be the number of the digits of $\ell$ in base $b$. Also, let $c_i$ be the $i$-th digit (from the right) of $\ell+1$ in base $b$. Let $N$ be the number of the digits of $\ell+1$ in base $b$.

Then, we can write
$$\ell=\overline{a_na_{n-1}\cdots a_2a_1}\qquad\text{and}\qquad \ell+1=\overline{c_Nc_{N-1}\cdots c_2c_1}$$
(For example, if $\ell=19$ and $b=3$, then $n=3$ and $a_1=1,a_2=0$ and $a_3=2$.)

- If $a_1\not=b-1$, then we have $N=n$ and $c_1=a_1+1$. Also, $c_i=a_i$ holds for every $2\le i\le n$. So, we have $D(\ell+1,b)-D(\ell,b)=1$ from which $(1)$ follows.
- If there is a positive integer $s\ (\lt n)$ such that $a_1=a_2=\cdots=a_s=b-1$ and $a_{s+1}\not=b-1$, then we have $N=n$ with $c_{s+1}=a_{s+1}+1$. Also, $c_i=0$ holds for every $1\le i\le s$. Also, $c_{i}=a_i$ holds for every $s+2\le i\le n$. So, we have $$\begin{align}&D(\ell+1,b)-D(\ell,b)
  \\\\&=\bigg(s(b-1)+a_{s+1}+a_{s+2}+a_{s+3}+\cdots+a_n\bigg)
  \\&\qquad\qquad -\bigg((a_{s+1}+1)+a_{s+2}+a_{s+3}+\cdots +a_n\bigg)
  \\\\&=s(\underbrace{b-1}_{\text{even}})-1\equiv 1\pmod 2\end{align}$$from which $(1)$ follows.
- If $a_i=b-1$ for every $1\le i\le n$, then $N=n+1$ and $c_{N}=1$. Also, $c_i=0$ holds for every $1\le i\le N-1$. So, we have $$D(\ell+1,b)-D(\ell,b)=n(\underbrace{b-1}_{\text{even}})-1\equiv 1\pmod 2$$ from which $(1)$ holds.$\quad\blacksquare$

It follows from the lemma that if both $a$ and $b$ are odd, then $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^a(-1)^{D(k, b)}=-1$.

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4171581/78967) has proved that if $a$ is odd and $b$ is even, then $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^a(-1)^{D(k, b)}=-1$.

Therefore, we can say that if $a$ is odd, then $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^a(-1)^{D(k, b)}=-1$.

So, if $c\equiv 2\pmod3$ and $a\equiv1\pmod2$, then we have
$$\begin{align}f(a,b,c)&=\sum_{k=1}^ac^{D(k, b)}
\\\\&\equiv\sum_{k=1}^a(-1)^{D(k, b)}\pmod 3 
\\\\&\equiv 2\pmod 3\end{align}$$

So, the second claim is true.

---

> 3. what is criteria for $f(a, b, c)\pmod3$ when $c\equiv2\pmod3$ and $a\equiv 0\pmod2$?

It follows from the lemma that if $a$ is even and $b$ is odd, then $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^a(-1)^{D(k, b)}=0$.

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4171581/78967) has proved that if both $a$ and $b$ are even, then $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^a(-1)^{D(k, b)}=-1-(-1)^{D(a+1,b)}$.

So, if $c\equiv 2\pmod 3$ and $a\equiv 0\pmod 2$, then we have
$$\begin{align}f(a,b,c)&=\sum_{k=1}^ac^{D(k, b)}
\\\\&\equiv \sum_{k=1}^a(-1)^{D(k, b)}\pmod 3
\\\\&\equiv \begin{cases}-1-(-1)^{D(a+1,b)}\pmod 3&\text{if $b$ is even}
\\\\0\pmod 3&\text{if $b$ is odd}\end{cases}
\\\\&\equiv\begin{cases}1\pmod 3&\text{if both $b$ and $D(a+1,b)$ are even}\\\\ 0\pmod 3&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't get this $\ell=\overline{Xp\underbrace{(b-1)(b-1)\cdots (b-1)}_{d}}$. Can you please explain what is it exactly?

Comment: @Pruthviraj : I should have explained the part more clearly. I have just rewritten the proof of the lemma.

Comment: How far can we go to determine when $D(a , b\text{=even})$  will be even?

Comment: @Pruthviraj : I have tried to determine when $D(a,b=\text{even})$ will be even, but I don't think I can. I've found the following small results. Let $a=a_nb^{n-1}+a_{n-1}b^{n-2}+\cdots +a_2b+a_1$. (1) If $b$ is even, then $a-a_1$ is even. (2) If $a-a_1$ is odd, then $b$ is odd. (3) $D(a,b)=a_n+a_{n-1}+\cdots+a_1\equiv a\pmod{b-1}$.